# Solving the inequality equation in Mathematica

Tags: functions, inequalities

I am trying to solve the following inequality equation in Mathematica:

```
12 Sin[300 t] >= 8
```

I want to find the values of `t` that satisfy this inequality. I have tried using the `Solve` and `Reduce` functions, but I haven't been successful so far. Here's the code I've used:

```
Solve[12 Sin[300 t] >= 8, t]
```

and

```
Reduce[12 Sin[300 t] >= 8, t]
```

Unfortunately, both attempts didn't work. Could someone please guide me on how to correctly solve this inequality equation in Mathematica?

Comment: Try Reduce[12 Sin[300 t] >= 8, t, Reals]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simplifying to look at one cycle:

```
res = Reduce[Sin[300 t] >= 2/3 && 0 < t < Pi/150, t]
```

yields: 1/300 ArcSin[2/3] <= t <= 1/300 ([Pi] - ArcSin[2/3])

Visualing:

```
pts = {res[[1]], res[[-1]]};
Plot[Sin[300 t], {t, 0, Pi/150}, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {pts, {2/3}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Arrowheads[{-.03, .03}], Arrow[{#, 0} & /@ pts]}]
```

[image]